# ROS mavros build error

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, mavlink

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3

OS: Raspbian Stretch

ROS: Kinetic

---

When attempting to add mavros to a [pre-made image](https://medium.com/@rosbots/ready-to-use-image-raspbian-stretch-ros-opencv-324d6f8dcd96), I `rosdep` throws an error.

Following instructions from [source installation](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md) instructions, I end up at line:

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y`

but get the error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
image_geometry: No definition of [opencv3] for OS version [stretch]
mavros: No definition of [geographic_msgs] for OS version [stretch]
mavros_msgs: No definition of [geographic_msgs] for OS version [stretch]
mavros_extras: No definition of [tf] for OS version [stretch]
test_mavros: No definition of [control_toolbox] for OS version [stretch]
cv_bridge: No definition of [opencv3] for OS version [stretch]
```

Because I'm in Raspbian Stretch, I instead use the command:

`rosdep install -y –from-paths src –ignore-src –rosdistro kinetic -r –os=debian:stretch`

but get the error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource –from-paths
ROS path [0]=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/pi/rosbots_catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

I have also even tried [this method](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros-release), however, I still do not have `mavros (kinetic)` on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Think You Need To Compile From Source.

Why Not Install With apt-get?

Try sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-mavros?

Comment: I've tried that. However, it says something like `E: ros-kinetic-mavros not found` (off the top of my memory)

Comment: It Seems That Raspian Have A Lot Of Issues With ROS [here's Their Issue On This](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/issues/709) They Also Recommend Compiling Everything From Source Not Just Mavros